# extract id from angular option

Tags: angular

Maybe I'm arguing something wrong my title, but the idea I think is a bit clear, I need to send the id of that data to be stored in my database I am sending but it is the name of the area

```
<div class="name margen">Area
  <select name="idarea" id="idarea" [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado"
    (change)="capturar()">
<option *ngFor="let dato of areas" ng-value="dato.idArea"
  value="{{dato.idArea}}">
  {{dato.NameArea}}</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why if ou try like this `[value]="dato.idArea"` without `ng-value` ?

Comment: It affects something, it does not fix the extraction of the id if I remove one or the other